# getActiveCell() wont work for me on google scripts

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've been trying to do a quick code for someone that will change the background color of a cell in google sheets when they input a specific phrase. The code runs fine with no errors but it doesn't produce anything on the spread sheet.  Any help would be amazing.

This is the code i have:

```
function ChangeCellHighlight() {

  //returning value of active cell
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet =ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();  


  //typing "Hay" will trigger cell background color 
  if  (cell == 'Hay') {  color
     cell.setBackgroundRGB(255, 0, 0); //red cell background        
  }
}
```

Comment: @coder-croc Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-written this to work. Rather than using getSheets()[0], I have changed this to getActiveSheet() which means the active sheet the current use is on. If it was to be specific you can change this to getSheetByName("SHEETNAME"). Most importantly in the IF statement where it calls 'Cell' it gets the cell but not the value so i have added, cell.getValue(). I have also added an onEdit() function which is a stored function in appscript. When you edit a cell it calls the function declared within it.

```
function ChangeCellHighlight() {

      //Get Current Google Sheet, Get Active Sheet Tab.
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
      //Get Active Cell.
      var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
      //If clause - does cell == "Hay"  
      if(cell.getValue() == "Hay") {
        //If YES change background to red.
        cell.setBackground("red");
      } else {
       //Anything else do nothing.
       //Do nothing or you could have Logger.log("Cell not equal to Hay");
      }
    }
    //This will run every time an edit is made.
    function onEdit(){ 
     ChangeCellHighlight(); 
    }
```